# Trying to use std::sort() with custom objects

Tags: c++, sorting, object, vector

I have looked up a few tutorials online. I have tried it on mine but the problem is `std::sort()` does not execute anything! Here is my whole code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#ifndef _card_h
#define _card_h

enum Suit {
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
};

enum Rank {
    TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
};

class Card {
    public:
        Card();
        Card(Rank, Suit);
        ~Card();
        Rank GetRank();
        Suit GetSuit();
        string ToString();
    private:
        Rank rank;
        Suit suit;
};
#endif

Card::Card() {
}

Card::Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
    this->rank = rank;
    this->suit = suit;
}

Card::~Card() {}

Rank Card::GetRank() {
    return rank;
}

Suit Card::GetSuit() {
    return suit;
}

string Card::ToString() {
    string cardName = "";
    switch (rank) {
        case TWO   : cardName += "2"; break;
        case THREE : cardName += "3"; break;
        case FOUR  : cardName += "4"; break;
        case FIVE  : cardName += "5"; break;
        case SIX   : cardName += "6"; break;
        case SEVEN : cardName += "7"; break;
        case EIGHT : cardName += "8"; break;
        case NINE  : cardName += "9"; break;
        case TEN   : cardName += "T"; break;
        case JACK  : cardName += "J"; break;
        case QUEEN : cardName += "Q"; break;
        case KING  : cardName += "K"; break;
        case ACE   : cardName += "A"; break;
    }
    switch (suit) {
        case CLUBS    : cardName += "C"; break;
        case DIAMONDS : cardName += "D"; break;
        case HEARTS   : cardName += "H"; break;
        case SPADES   : cardName += "S"; break;
    }
    return cardName;
}

#ifndef _cardcomparer_h
#define _cardcomparer_h

class CardComparer {  
    public:
        bool operator() (Card*, Card*);
    private:
        Card* firstCard;
        Card* secondCard;
};
#endif

bool CardComparer::operator() (Card* firstCard, Card* secondCard) {
    this->firstCard = firstCard;
    this->secondCard = secondCard;
    cout << "in Cardcompare! " << endl;
    if (firstCard->GetRank() == secondCard->GetRank()) {
        return firstCard->GetSuit() > secondCard->GetSuit();
    }
    else {
        return firstCard->GetRank() > secondCard->GetRank();
    }
}

#ifndef _hand_h
#define _hand_h
const int CARDS_IN_HAND = 5;
class Hand {
    public:
        Hand(int);
        ~Hand();
        void AddCard(Card*);
        string ToString();

    private:
        int cardCount;
        int playerID;
        vector<Card*> cards;

};
#endif

Hand::Hand(int playerID) {
    this->playerID = playerID;
    cards.reserve(CARDS_IN_HAND);
    cardCount = 0;
}

Hand::~Hand() {
    cards.clear();
}

void Hand::AddCard(Card* newCard) {
    cards[cardCount] = newCard;
    cardCount++;
    sort(cards.begin(), cards.end(),CardComparer());
}

string Hand::ToString() {
    stringstream playerCards;
    playerCards << "Player " << this->playerID << " -";
    for (int i = 0; i < cardCount; i++ ){
        playerCards << " " << cards[i]->ToString();
    }
    return playerCards.str();
}

int main() {
    vector<Hand*> hands;
    hands.reserve(1);
    hands[0] = new Hand(0);
    hands[0]->AddCard(new Card((Rank)4, (Suit)1));
    hands[0]->AddCard(new Card((Rank)8, (Suit)2));
    hands[0]->AddCard(new Card((Rank)5, (Suit)1));
    hands[0]->AddCard(new Card((Rank)2, (Suit)0));
    hands[0]->AddCard(new Card((Rank)7, (Suit)3));
    cout << hands[0]->ToString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is line 133(`sort(cards.begin(), cards.end(),CardComparer());`) does not execute. Whether I comment it out or in the result does not change I even added an extra line on 93(`cout << "in Cardcompare! " << endl;`), where it prints out something if it uses bool. However it does not. I cannot find where the problem is. What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you store firstCard and secondCard in the cardComparer? You do not need it as it seems.

Comment: You would also be much better off without using pointers and `new` everywhere. In real life, a hand is a "vector" of cards, not a set of pointers to cards. That works much better in a program as well, like `Hand.push_back(Card(ACE, SPADES));`. In real life, I also pick up all the cards and sort them at the end, I don't resort the hand for each card I pick up. The program could model that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the vector does no know you tried to add the cards in `AddCard`, or more precisely, you did not *really* add those cards, because you did not call `push_back` but simply put the pointer somewhere in memory. Yes, the vector owns that memory due to the call to `reserve`, but it thinks it's empty. Therefore `begin()` and `end()` give the same iterator and sort sorts exactly 0 elements.

Look up the chapter about `vector` and other containers in your textbook of choice. You don't need to keep track of the number of cards (`cardCount`), because the vector does that perfectly for you, if used right.

Comment: @user1292095: Also note the same problem with vector `hands` in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues with your code that need to be addressed. One of the most important is the fact that you are currently leaking a lot of memory. You are declaring `vector<Card*>` and allocating memory but never freeing it. Also the way you are entering data into your vector is not correct. The reserve function does not actually create new elements, it simply reserves the memory for them.

Here is a cleaned up version including getting your sort to work correctly. Hopefully by studying it you will learn some things about C++.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

enum Suit {
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
};

enum Rank {
    TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
};
const char *card_lookup[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
const char *suit_lookup[] = {"C", "D", "H", "S" };

class Card {
    public:
        Card::Card() 
        { }
        Card::Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) 
        {
            this->rank = rank;
            this->suit = suit;
        }
        Card::~Card() 
        {}
        Rank Card::GetRank() const
        {
            return rank;
        }

        Suit Card::GetSuit() const
        {
            return suit;
        }
        string Card::ToString() {
            string cardName = card_lookup[rank];
            cardName += suit_lookup[suit];
            return cardName;
        }
    private:
        Rank rank;
        Suit suit;
};

bool operator<(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs)
{
    if(lhs.GetRank() == rhs.GetRank())
        return lhs.GetSuit() < rhs.GetSuit();
    else
        return lhs.GetRank() < rhs.GetRank();

}

const int CARDS_IN_HAND = 5;
class Hand {
    public:
        Hand::Hand(int playerID) 
        {
            this->playerID = playerID;
        }
        Hand::~Hand() 
        { }

        void Hand::AddCard(Card newCard) 
        {
            cards.push_back(newCard);
        }
        string Hand::ToString() 
        {
            sort(cards.begin(), cards.end());

            stringstream playerCards;
            playerCards << "Player " << this->playerID << " -";
            for (auto it = cards.begin(), end = cards.end(); it != end; ++it)
                playerCards << " " << it->ToString();

            return playerCards.str();
        }

    private:
        int playerID;
        vector<Card> cards;

};


int main() {
    vector<Hand> hands;
    Hand h(1);
    h.AddCard(Card(SIX, DIAMONDS));
    h.AddCard(Card(TEN, HEARTS));
    h.AddCard(Card(SEVEN, DIAMONDS));
    h.AddCard(Card(FOUR, CLUBS));
    h.AddCard(Card(NINE, SPADES));
    hands.push_back(h);
    cout << hands[0].ToString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```